# Cannot run sudo when using ngrok to develop locally for Slack with a windows PC

Tags: node.js, windows, slack-api, ngrok

I'm looking at the following document: https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tunneling-with-ngrok. I cannot get passed 'step 4' as I'm running Windows and it is geared for Mac.

On step 4, it is asking me to run:

```
sudo node index.js
```

`sudo` is not a command prompt command and I'm unsure how to execute the code. What command should I use to replace `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are Windows, you don't need [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). Assuming you have [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) installed on your Windows machine, you should be able to run `node index.js`

Comment: ...>Desktop>Slackapp>node index.js
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I got the following response. Nothing happens as well when I type '> index.js'

nodejs is located in my desktop folder above index.js

Answer (score 0):

I think there was some saving issues. It's been resolved.